# if statements and math.random

Tags: java, if-statement, jcombobox

I am trying to make an if statement that when a user picks from a combo box and it so happens to be the number that was determined from math.random, it will display a message. I already have the if statement set up. However, this part isnt working.
I am unable to tell if it is working or not because I cant test it. This is because I do not know which date is the random number.

```
int RandomDate = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*31);
    Out1.setText(RandomDate);
...
...
...
else if(Day.getSelectedItem().equals(RandomDate))
    {
        Out1.setText("This Day is Fully Booked");
    }
```

Out1 is a text area
Day is the name of my JComboBox

Thanks for the help. I probably just made a little mistake and don't know where I went wrong because I am new to Java

Comment: What is the expected and actual output?

Comment: when you say it isn't working, do you mean it's giving you a specific exception? or it's just not doing what you expect? If it's giving an exception, please show it here, if it's not what you expect, please let us know in which way it's misbehaving, so we can better assist with your problem :)

Comment: @AnubianNoob The expected output is for the user to pick a date that is not the value of the math.random

Comment: What is the content of `Day.getSelectedItem()` when your `if` block is run?

Comment: @AndrewArnold The combobox has a list of dates from 1 to 31. (days of the week)

Comment: Yes, but what is the value of `Day.getSelectedItem()`? Is it an integer? a date? a string? some other object?

Comment: @AndrewArnold An Integer I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Make the random number an instance variable of your class and populate it in your constructor. Add an action listener to your combo box (hopefully you did this already). In your actionPerformed() method, get the selected item and compare it to your random number instance variable:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class SamplePane extends JFrame implements ActionListener   {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1775096938821736542L;

    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JComboBox<Integer> combo;
    private int RandomDate;

    public SamplePane() {

        //for the frame
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300,200);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        //create combo box
        Integer[] nums = new Integer[31];
        for (int i=0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            nums[i] = i+1;
        }
        combo = new JComboBox<Integer>(nums);
        combo.addActionListener(this);
        add(combo);

        //create the random date
        RandomDate = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*31);

        //create a text area
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setText(Integer.toString(RandomDate));
        add(textArea);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SamplePane frame = new SamplePane();
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == combo) {
            int selItem = (Integer)combo.getSelectedItem();
            if (selItem == RandomDate) {
                textArea.setText("This Day is Fully Booked");
            } else {
                textArea.setText(Integer.toString(RandomDate));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what this is, I have no idea how to use this. I'm sure it works though